# android - how to put actionbar size in dimens resources file

Tags: android, android-resources, android-api-levels

I need to have actionbar size in the dimens resources folder , I need to have different size for different api version  .

I've tried these code but all of then ran into an error :

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
?attr/actionBarSize
?actionBarSize
```

when I launch the app ,I get this error :

```
 You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

how can I put actionbar size in the resource folder ?

Comment: where is you XML definition? for us to make it easy to understand, is better to paste the snippet here!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    :
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarTheme" />
```

with:

```
<style name="AppBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    :
</style>
```

EDIT: I also have this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Using the toolbar so no need to show action bar or title -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    :
</style>
```